# Creating a custom applet (AppIndicator?) Unity

Tags: unity

I have a little GTK application I've created which is basically a simple Switch. I would like to see if anyone knows if it is possible to add to the menubar in ubuntu. Almost like the power button in the corner. I'd just like to be able to have it sit there and toggle it from time to time to have it run custom code (which turns on my air conditioner via curl/wifi smart plug) similar to a widget I suppose.
So rather than having a separate application it just sits there neatly up the top. Any ideas on how to do this if it is possible which I will assume it is but I don't know how ;-)

Executive summary; take a standard GTK switch button and attempt to embed it into the unity menu bar, is it possible?

Thanks
Jack